# Combine duplicate rows but keep class information?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-management, duplication

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to avoid combining and deleting duplicate values manually. I'm working with parcel data, and based on some property information, each parcel is either in group a, b, c, multiple groups, or no groups at all. I had to do some select by location processing to get the lists of the parcels for each group.

I want to create a master list that combines the records from each group, removes duplicates, but still retains the group information. For example, if I had:

```
John Doe, 123 Main Street, Group A
John Doe, 123 Main Street, Group B
John Doe, 123 Main Street, Group C
Mary Smith, 321 Pleasant Street, Group B
Mary Smith, 321 Pleasant Street, Group C
Alex Jones, 111 Park Ave, Group C
```

I would want the output to be:

```
John Doe, 123 Main Street, Group A, Group B, Group C
Mary Smith, 321 Pleasant Street, Group B, Group C
Alex Jones, 111 Park Ave, Group C
```

I already created GROUP_1, GROUP_2, and GROUP_3 field in the respective attribute tables and have tried merge, union, append, and even some manual select by location add to selection and cannot figure it out for the life of me.

I am using ArcMap.

Comment: You have a one to many situation. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69892/creating-a-spatial-many-to-one-join  Try searching help and this forum on that; right now my searching is not working.

Comment: elcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Would a python solution be acceptable?

Comment: Hi everyone, another project came my way and I had to put this one on the back burner. Thanks for all your input. I'll post a detailed description of my process soon so anyone one else with this issue could follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Pivot Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/pivot-table.htm):

> Creates a table from the input table by reducing redundancy in records
>   and flattening one-to-many relationships.

[image]

If you also have geometries, dissolve or do whatever you want with them first then join the pivot table.